# Ltspice blackbox

Tags: ltspice, simulation

Is it possible to create a blackbox that is defined with an equation in Ltspice. Something like this:
[image]

Comment: Please improve your question and make it more specific by eliminating the words "is it possible" and replace it with better details.

Comment: @VoltageSpike The question was answered, the answer was deleted... "Is it possible" can be replaced with "how to" but what's the point? I was just interested in how could I "model" some ic for which I coudn't find a correct model. INA126 to be precise. It's a simple question, no need for more details..

Comment: What kind of black box? do you want to create a graphical object from a sub circuit? What is the problem? Be descriptive

Comment: @Hedgehog What you want is probably the very first thing a tutorial teaches when making a subcircuit: a behavioural source with an expression involving one or more inputs. A subcircuit *is* a blackbox, one in which you can either allow prying eyes, or not. The deleted answer was on point, just the part with the `.param` was off, which could have been omitted.

Comment: @Hedgehog TI has a PSPICE model for the [INA126](https://www.ti.com/lit/zip/sbom021). The model is a subcircuit. You can draw a symbol and link the subcircuit to the symbol. LTSpice is generally compatible with PSPICE syntax. You can find tutorials on the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used LTspice to know if you can do "black boxes" defined by equation (you can do sub-circuits, and then view those as black boxes if you wish, in your case you might look into op-amp based substractors, or into using a controled voltage source).

But in any case, there is no way you could define a black box like your example (in any software I believe, excepted it it makes some assumptions that are not explicit in your drawing) :

- first, your output is not defined : you get a voltage Input1 - Input2, but without any reference point, so it don't make sense (either you take it relative to input 1 or 2, or you need to add a ground pin as reference).
- second, you lack supply pins (well, that might be acceptable in a high level simulation)
- last and not least, you haven't defined the currents flowing in each pin, so that makes any simulation impossible (a simulator needs to simulate voltage and current). The simplest way would be to define an imput impedance (or resistance) for each pin (nb : the second end must be connected somewhere, for example the missing ground pin). If you want an "ideal" commponent, you could define infinite input impedance, and 0 output resistance.

EDIT :
I think to I have found the solution : your can use "arbitrary behavioral voltage sources" : you can have a voltage related with nearly any expression to any voltages/currents in your simulation. This is enough for your simple example.

If you want something more complexe, use a sub-component in which you put your arbitrary behavioral voltage source and the input/output impedances you need.

For more informations about arbitrary behavioral voltage sources, you can have a look at [this tutorial from LT](https://www.analog.com/en/education/education-library/videos/5579264350001.html)

Comment: Image is purely an example.. there was an answer here that was deleted for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want.

If you are talking about making a subcircuit for a block, you can create your own graphical symbols from subcircuits: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bOzKJr62Uc8

If you are talking about a black box that no one can see the inside, LT spice offers a way to encrypt subcircuits. Create a sub-circuit, then encrypt it. You can pass The instructions to do so are located here:

[How to create encrypted spice subcircuit/schematic and use it as symbol in other schematics?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/487951/how-to-create-encrypted-spice-subcircuit-schematic-and-use-it-as-symbol-in-other)